# Trigger :hover selector when dragging

Tags: jquery, css, drag-and-drop, hover, draggable

I'm having kind of an issue about a drag & drop  system I'm currently developing.

I have a `:hover` style on a div the user can drop something on.
It works when I simply hover over it, but not when I am dragging an element.

Is there a workaround to show that style even when dragging?

```js
$(document).on('dragstart','#draggable',function(e){
  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("data",$(this).attr('data-text'));
});

$(document).on('drop','#droppable',function(e){
 console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("data"));
});

$(document).on('dragover','#droppable',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-family: Arial
}
    
#droppable{
  border: 2px solid green;
}

#droppable:hover{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
    
#draggable{
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="droppable">Hover me !</div>
<div id="draggable" draggable="true" data-text="I exist too ! :(">Drag me !</div>
```

Comment: How about creating a class and adding it on dragstart?

Comment: I don't want to change anything on `dragstart`, I want to change the style of the div I'm hovering.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Heh, I finally found the [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dragenter_event) I was looking for, I couldn't find them before :

```
.on('dragenter') // Triggers when you enter your element

.on('dragleave') // Triggers when you leave your element
```

***Demo:***

```js
$(document).on('dragstart','#draggable',function(e){
  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("data",$(this).attr('data-text'));
});

$(document).on('drop','#droppable',function(e){
    console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("data"));
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
});

$(document).on('dragenter','#droppable',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('hover');
});

$(document).on('dragleave','#droppable',function(e){
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-family: Arial
}
    
#droppable{
  border: 2px solid green;
}

#droppable:hover,#droppable.hover{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
    
#draggable{
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="droppable">Hover me !</div>
<div id="draggable" draggable="true" data-text="I exist too ! :(">Drag me !</div>
```

Comment: According to https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/02/html-drag-drop-api-react/ you should use `dragenter` instead of `dragover` since the latter is triggered for each movement.

Comment: how to do this in pure JS

Comment: @JenuelGanawed Use `yourElement.addEventListener('dragenter', () => { ... })`

Comment: Note, `dragleave` is not triggered when you release the mouse button. You probably want to also handle leave in the `change` event.

Answer (score 0):

In Dropzone v 5.7.2 (I didn't check other/previous versions) whenever you are dragging a file over the initialized dropzone container, the Dropzone library adds a new class "dz-drag-hover" to that container.

So now it is very easy to add extra styling to that, e.g.:

```
.dz-drag-hover {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```